# Ada programming non-contiguous subtype range

Tags: arrays, range, ada

Is it possible for a subtype range to have a non-contiguous component?

For example, I have a subtype range similar to this:

```
subtype My_Subtype is My_Num_Type range Min .. Max;
```

I want to add an additional valid value to this range to avoid checking for a single value in the logic.

So pseudo-code might look like this:

```
subtype My_Subtype is My_Num_Type range Min .. Max also Outlier;
```

I want the implementation logic to look something like this:

```
Is_Valid := My_Val in My_Subtype;
```

Note: I realize I can do this very simply and cleanly with an "Is_Valid" routine. This is more a thought experiment on min/maxing my code.

Comment: The Static_Predicate or Dynamic_Predicate aspects might do what you want: https://docs.adacore.com/spark2014-docs/html/ug/en/source/type_contracts.html

Comment: Predicates actually do look like what I want to solve a bigger issue. Sadly we are in an Ada 95 environment. I don't think I can use 2012.

Answer (score 3):

You could encapsulate your type in a private record, where the conversion routine from your full integer type raises a `Constraint_Error` for invalid values.

There are two naming conventions for such routines `"+"` and `"+"` or `To_<private type>` and `To_<full integer type>`.  I prefer the shorter one, but some people might consider it to be too surprising for the reader of source using the operations.

Comment: As a general principal, when trying to implement a type with features not directly available in the language, you should use a private type.